# Degiro Oxy non-tradable stocks

Tags: stocks, financial-literacy

A little while ago, I bought 61 shares of OPC (Occidental Petroleum Corp, now known as Oxy) traded in the Xetra exchange through Degiro.

A couple of days ago, the 61 shares are still there, but now I also have 7 non-tradable shares whose price is listed as 0,0001:

[image: degiro non-tradable shares]

I see nothing over [Oxy's investors' page](https://www.oxy.com/investors/Pages/default.aspx) about what this could be about.

Degiro support told me this was due to a corporate action, but said they are only a broker, they do not analyze portfolios.

I figure this could happen if the stock stopped trading in Xetra, which is not the case. What could these non-tradable shares be about? It never happened to me and I see little information online, so I would really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

​
Occidental Petroleum Corporation issued warrants to common stock owners on June 6th.  There was a distribution of 1/8th of a warrant for every share of common stock  owned (exercisable from August 3, 2020 through August 3, 2027).  No fractional warrants were issued.

You own 61 shares so you are entitled to 7 warrants (the integer value of 61 divided by 8).

On my trading platform (USA), I see them traded on 6 different exchanges for about $4.82 so they're not worthless (contrary to your comment).  Google "Occidental Petroleum warrants" for more info.

Comment: According to [Stock Warrants To Trade On Occidental Petroleum](https://commonstockwarrants.com/stock-warrants-to-trade-on-occidental-petroleum-oxy/), trading began on Monday 3rd. If the OP's image is "from a couple of days ago", could the "worthless" value be because it was before trading began?

Comment: @TripeHound - Yes, that makes sense and  would resolve the value discrepancy.

Comment: In the past, I have saved my money in investment funds and ETFs, never stocks directly, so I am pretty new to this. (I bought shares of this company because I thought it was too beaten down.) By "worthless", I meant that it was listed as 0.0001€ in my broker Degiro. I didn't know what warrants were, and I missed the news about this. My understanding is that I am able to trade these warrants into stock for $22, which is obviously undesirable now but might become valuable. Or I can sell these at NYSE. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Ricardo Cruz - You're welcome.  Barring and special terms and contingencies (not the case here), warrants are just long term options.  Keep in mind that if OXY appreciates, so too will the warrants, albeit at a slower rate.  They can be sold at any time.  But given that they have a lot of years until they expire,  you can ride them for a good while without much concern for time decay (the price decreases).  Don't ride then all the way until expiration.

Comment: Just one question that still confuses me. Why does Oxy say this is to prioritize liquidity? How does this benefit Oxy? Why would any company benefit from warrants? My only guess is that they think this move might assure investors that the company is confident that it will bounce back (above $22) which might make new investors more confident in buying it. It makes sense particularly because this seems to have been announced with some time in advance. That is the reason why a company would issue warrants, right?

Comment: My guess is that the statement "prioritize liquidity" is a generic statement regarding the solvency of the company (cutting the dividend, divesting some assets from the APC merger, etc.) rather than something to do with the warrants.  Warrants are usually provided as an enticement to shareholders, in particular with IPOs.  In this case, not only is it a good deal for shareholders should OXY's price rise nicely but it may be a bit of PR to reassure investors.